# Reverting Back to old computer name in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, computer-name

I access a PC remotely, I changed its computer name accidentally but not yet restarted it. Now I Want to revert back to the old name because If I restart I would lose access. Can I revert back without restarting It?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `IP address` of this computer, then you will not lose access to it, you can also connect remotely knowing the `IP address`, in the line where you indicate the name of the PC - specify its `IP`.

> Can I revert back without restarting It?
> As far as I know, no. A reboot is required.